# Do I need a transit visa for Toronto?

Tags: visas, canada, transit-visas

I am a citizen of Trinidad & Tobago. I am about to book a flight from Port of Spain Trinidad to Aruba connecting in Toronto for 1 hour. Do I need a Canadian visa for this connection?

Comment: A very long detour but we need to know your citizenship to answer.

Comment: We have to ask why you are taking this long way round. Because border control will probably ask.

Comment: @DJClayworth Border control may well ask, but why do __we__ have to know? The question is about transit visas, not sensible routing.

Comment: Trinidad and Tobago citizen

Comment: @DJClayworth surely the answer is that a Canadian airline offered an attractive fare.

Answer (score 1):

The Canadian government [Immigration & Citizenship web site](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas.asp) says you'll need a visa to transit or visit Canada. The same page will take you to instructions on how to apply, too.

Comment: Why the unexplained downvote?